# Android : Layout background inside toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar

I want to create like bellow image.

[image]

For creating like this I write the bellow code.

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="posoft.shariful.rupkotharpata.Profile"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/p1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="@string/test_user_full_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:text="@string/test_user"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It working. But the problem is, **It don't show app toolbar**.

**Note :** The tools of toolbar working.

Now how I can show toolbar or toolbar tools?

Comment: you can use toolbar and set its height to wrap content then put above layout as toolbar child .. BOOM you got a tool bar with this view ;)

Comment: brother check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your LinearLayout is displaying over your toolbar(Views inside a RelativeLayout display over one other, and you haven't mentioned any view to display above or below the other one).
Assign an id to your toolbar, and instruct your LinearLayout to be below it, something like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

You might also need to increase your parent RelativeLayout's height from 220dp to something like 250dp to accommodate both the children without clipping the bottom one.

Comment: It's simple, easy and working! But one more problem. If I use toolbar background color it show toolbar color perfectly. But I use toolbar background color **#00ffffff**.
It means there are no color like **png**. But in this case toolbar take **white background color**.
Can you tell me why it show this problem. please.
And thank you for your answer.

Comment: That is happening because your parent RelativeLayout doesn't have any background. Just move 
android:background="@drawable/b1"
from the LinearLayout below the toolbar to the parent RelativeLayout and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `AppBarLayout` over there.

For your reference I have posted one xml file. refer this..

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.news.moneycontrol.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_dashboard"
        />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <!-- <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/flexible_image"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:src="@mipmap/home_cover"
                  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                  app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>-->          


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <com.news.moneycontrol.progressbar.CircularProgressView
        android:id="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:cpv_animAutostart="false"
        app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
        app:cpv_thickness="4dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/no_internet"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_connection_error" />


    <com.xxx.CustomFont
        android:id="@+id/text_internet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="No Internet Connection"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

hope you have listed below necessary gradles!

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new scroll activity then in activity layout file put imageview in collapsing toolbar layout

```
     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/test_background_image"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/groupImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the layout in `toolbar` as follows

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:contentDescription="todo"
                        android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"


                        />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:text="Full name"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="19sp"
                            android:text="user"
                            android:textColor="@color/theme_color"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```